# EntryPointNotFoundException when calling DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(Container));

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, unity-container

I've got an MVC project and I've been doing DI in my WebAPI controllers for quite some time using a IHttpControllerActivator.

```
configuration.Services.Replace(
                typeof(IHttpControllerActivator),
                new UnityCompositionRoot(Container));
```

Now I need to use DI in an MVC controller so tried adding this line from the Unity.MVC project.

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(Container));
```

But I'm getting an EntryPointNotFound exception when trying to set the resolver with the following stack trace.

```
   at System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.CacheDependencyResolver..ctor(IDependencyResolver resolver)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.InnerSetResolver(IDependencyResolver resolver)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.SetResolver(IDependencyResolver resolver)
   at GRP2App.Web.App_Start.DependencyConfig.RegisterDependencys(HttpConfiguration configuration) in c:\Dev\SVN-Git\GRP2.5\GRP2App\GRP2App.Web\App_Start\DependencyConfig.cs:line 96
```

I've updated all my Unity nu-get packages so all the different projects should be on the same version. I'm not really sure what else to try.

Comment: I must have because it's working fine. I can't remember the actual fix but I'll take a look at the code I've got in that area and try to post a reasonable answer.

Comment: I've added the answer which I think resolved the issue for me but I don't want to mark it as correct in case it was something else. Can you let me know if this fixes your issue so I can mark it as correct. Otherwise I'll remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to remember this was an issue with upgrading from MVC 4 to MVC 5.

I upgraded using NuGet but there are several version numbers in the assembly redirects and razor engine sections of the web.config file which need updating.

This article contains full instructions with all the different places where the version numbers need upgrading.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2

This was the important part for me.

> Update all elements that contain “System.Web.WebPages.Razor”  from 
>   version “2.0.0.0”  to  version“3.0.0.0”. If this section contains
>   “System.Web.WebPages”,  update those elements from  version “2.0.0.0”
>   to  version“3.0.0.0”